# How do Logout User When Session Expires

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.net 4.5, Ef 6, Identity 2
I have implemented the session in my app by the following code in

> web.config

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.1\SQLEXPRESS;User Id=sa;Password=123456;" timeout="1"></sessionState>
```

In `Global.asax` file

```
public void Session_end()
{
   Redirect("LogOut");
}
```

But, when session expire the app is not logging out. it showing error at the session variable

> variable is not set an instance of oject

I want to logout the user when the session expires.Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to log out a user when a session times out or ends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413886/how-to-log-out-a-user-when-a-session-times-out-or-ends)

Comment: Session has *nothing* to do with logging out a user.  You need your authentication mechanism to timeout, not session.

Comment: @Erik Philips can be explain with an exmple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session timeout does not work ( is set in web.config )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862907/session-timeout-does-not-work-is-set-in-web-config)