# ASP.NET Identity Web Forms Force logout after 30 mins

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I am using the built-in ASP.NET identity template in VS 2015. I have all the proper AspNet tables in my LocalDb, and can manage users and roles effectively.

However, I want to make sure that users log out when finished. How can I efficiently implement a way to force logout after the user has been inactive for, say, 30 minutes? I don't want to start a 30 minute timer and then log the user out if he/she is still in the middle of their session. However, I do want them to be logged out after 30 mins of no activity.

**Edited to add:** I have an application eith three different roles (Normal, Advanced, and Admin). The application allows users to see their data visualized in dashboards. Normal users can view, and that's all. Advanced can view as well as create new charts. Admin can do all the above, plus manage other users, create new accounts, etc. This application will be deployed on a server via IIS, and our customers will use it internally.

The reason I need to be able to automatically log users out, is if it's a shared computer they're on to see the dashboards. However, I need to be able to set this timeout function within the app, so that if they create a "Public" user, it never gets logged out. This would be in the case, for example, where they want to have the dashboards displayed on a TV screen in the breakroom or lobby to something to display their KPIs. So this "public" user needs to **not** get logged out after a set time.

Comment: You can use this? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413886/how-to-log-out-a-user-when-a-session-times-out-or-ends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413886/how-to-log-out-a-user-when-a-session-times-out-or-ends)

Comment: That's for FormsAuthentication, which is the "older way" of handling it, as I understand it. I'm looking for a way that falls under ASP.NET Identity (OWIN)